Connect Hands-Free Bluetooth headset to microcontroller?
For quite some time I have been looking for a way to connect a Bluetooth headset to a Bluetooth chip. In the end I would like to find a way to have something like this:
A ham-radio with a wired connection to a Bluetooth-chip/micro-controller/circuit which then auto connects to Bluetooth headsets when in reach.
At first I had the idea to use an ESP32 with something like the library: https://github.com/pschatzmann/ESP32-A2DP, but turns out there is no (at least I did not find any) library around which could do the hands free audio part, or any other way to have two audio streams for mic/audio at the same time.
My second idea was to use a Raspberry pi, with an additional USB sound device with microphone and audio jack which then could be wire connected to the ham radio. A little bash script would connect to the Bluetooth headset. Basically I would run those two commands to have both audio streams at the same time and forward them between Bluetooth and wired audio connection:
pacat -r --latency-msec=1 -d alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.mono-fallback | pacat -p --latency-msec=1 -d bluez_sink.0C_02_5B_00_2B_1E.headset_head_unit

pacat -r --latency-msec=1 -d bluez_source.0C_02_5B_00_2B_1E.headset_head_unit | pacat -p --latency-msec=1 -d alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-stereo

I played around with this path a little but very soon figured out that it has too many issues: the pi takes for ever to boot, it uses a lot of energy and the Bluetooth connections are very much unstable (once it is connected its ok, but to get there it takes some tries...)
Now I have (maybe) found another easier way: RN52-Bluetooth module.
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-52-ds-1.1r.pdf.
From the document it seems that it should be able to allow connections from for example headphones to it plus it already has the required audio circuit built in. Which is great - BUT it is for my understanding unreasonably expensive with 60+ USD (I could not even find an aliexpress clone...)
So my question is:

would a module like this work for the described application?
are there any cheap alternatives to that Bluetooth module (or what would be the appropriate search on google to find some ;) i am just not sure what exactly these modules are called ;) )
is there any other easy and affordable solution for that problem?

Any idea would be great!!

Audio in BT is just bytes. Observe what bytes a working setup (perhaps on another device such as a phone) sends and replicate. If a library you wish existed does not exist, consider making it.
